# Blazor Server Side Component - bindings not updating

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-server-side

Updating bound properties from the code behind is not updating the displayed SVG, however changing the values in the inputs does.  How can I change a bound property from the code behind and trigger a redraw to the SVG on the UI.

```cs
@page "/svg"
@using System.Timers

<h3>SVG Test</h3>

<div>
    <input type="text" @bind-value="X1"/>
    <input type="text" @bind-value="Y1"/>
    <input type="text" @bind-value="X2"/>
    <input type="text" @bind-value="Y2"/>
    
    <svg width="500" height="300">
        <line x1="@X1" y1="@Y1" x2="@X2" y2="@Y2" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:5"/>
    </svg>
</div>

@code {
    public int X1 { get; set; }
    public int Y1 { get; set; }
    public int X2 { get; set; }
    public int Y2 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        X1 = 25;
        Y1 = 25;
        X2 = 200;
        Y2 = 200;

        var timer = new Timer(1000){AutoReset = true};
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed");
            X2 -= 5;
            StateHasChanged();
        };
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

In the above code

- I can confirm the timer is firing (Elapsed message in the console).
- If I change a value (ie X1) in the input boxes and then change focus to another element (input), the value of X2 (as changed in elapsed) also updates (to the value it should be based on the number of elapsed events that have triggered).
- Also, the line changes accordingly in the SVG on loss of focus from the changed input.

How can I get it to refresh from the code behind rather than changing element focus. I thought that's what `StateHasChanged()` was for.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer:

Because the timer is running on a separate thread from the UI, `StateHasChanged()` needed to be run on the UI thread to update.

Instead of:

```
StateHasChanged();
```

Changed to:

```cs
InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged); // execute on the UI thread
```

Completed working demo for fun and anyone interested, walks the line around the outside (well 25px padded) of the SVG):

```cs
@page "/svg"
@using System.Timers

<h3>SVG Test</h3>

<div>
    <input type="text" @bind-value="X1"/>
    <input type="text" @bind-value="Y1"/>
    <input type="text" @bind-value="X2"/>
    <input type="text" @bind-value="Y2"/>

    <svg width="300" height="300">
        <line x1="@X1" y1="@Y1" x2="@X2" y2="@Y2" style="stroke:red;stroke-width:5"/>
    </svg>
</div>

@code {
    public int X1 { get; set; }
    public int Y1 { get; set; }
    public int X2 { get; set; }
    public int Y2 { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        X1 = 25;
        Y1 = 25;
        X2 = 25;
        Y2 = 275;

        const double interval = (double) 1000 / 60;
        var timer = new Timer(interval) {AutoReset = true};
        timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Elapsed");
            // Added this for demo purposes
            switch (X1)
            {
                case >= 25 and < 275 when Y1 == 25 && X2 == 25 && Y2 == 275: X1+=5; break;
                case 275 when Y1 == 25 && X2 == 25 && (Y2 is <= 275 and > 25): Y2-=5; break;
                case 275 when (Y1 is >= 25 and < 275) && X2 == 25 && Y2 == 25: Y1+=5; break;
                case 275 when Y1 == 275 && (X2 is >= 25 and < 275) && Y2 == 25: X2+=5; break;
                case <= 275 and > 25 when Y1 == 275 && X2 == 275 && Y2 == 25: X1-=5; break;
                case 25 when Y1 == 275 && X2 == 275 && Y2 is >= 25 and < 275: Y2+=5; break;
                case 25 when (Y1 is <= 275 and > 25) && X2 == 275 && Y2 == 275: Y1-=5; break;
                case 25 when Y1 == 25 && X2 is <= 275 and > 25 && Y2 == 275: X2-=5; break;
            }
            // Actual fix for original question
            InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        };
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```